# SUM IFS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I implement a Summation logic based on agreement of multiple true conditions, that is:

I have an input array:

value:    `[['dec','toy',12/4/2020,50],['dec','pen',14/4/2020,50],['dec','toy',14/4/2020,53],['dec','toy',4/4/2020,50],]`

header: `['month','object','day','score']`

Now I have a function that takes 4 parameters:

1. header array
2. value array
3. condition string

`function sumif(summationMetricHeader,header,value,condition)`

Where `condition` string is as follows:
`<value to be compared>@@<comparision operation>@@<ValueType>@@HeaderName,<value to be compared>@@<comparision operation>@@<ValueType>@@HeaderName...`

where @@ is the seperator specifying the 4 comparision params and , is the seperator between multiple conditions.

If all the condition is true then `summationHeaderMetric` should be added upon.

So for example:

value:    `[['dec','toy',12/4/2020,50],['dec','pen',14/4/2020,50],['dec','toy',14/4/2020,53],['dec','toy',4/4/2020,50],]`

header: `['month','object','day','score']`

summationMetric: `score`

condition string: `12/4/2020@@>=@@Date@@day,50@@>=@@Number@@score`

Now here it says sum only if day column is greater than equal to `12/4/2020` (and comparision must be date comparision as it's specified) and also where score is greater than equal to 50 (here comparision is number type)

So the output will be: 50 + 50 + 53 (as for the last element in values  array day column value is smaller than the specified condition)

In total there are threee comparisions:

1. Date
2. String
3. Number

for comparisions:

```
let decision = true;
if(stringElem.split("@@")[2] === 'Date')
        decision = decision && eval(`${new Date(stringElem.split("@@")[0]).getTime()}${stringElem.split("@@")[1]}${new Date(value[i]).getTime()}`)


else if(stringElem.split("@@")[2] === 'String')
        decision = decision && eval(`'${stringElem.split("@@")[0]}'${stringElem.split("@@)[1]}'${value[i]}'`)
```

I tried of using eval but am not able to format the string properly for comparision. Can anyone help me to solve this? I am not very deep into Javascript array methods and would love to know if there's any simpler way to code the same.

Here's a very simple version of the function I am trying to implement:

```
    function computeMetricwithConditions() {

  const headers = ['name', 'place','stats', 'score', 'date'];
  const data = [['o','b', 22, 2, '4/14/2021']];
  const conditions = [['o', '===','String','name'],
                      ['b', '===','String','place'],
                      ['4/14/2021','>=','Date','date'],
                      [2,'>=','Number','stats']];
  const hashMap = {};

  headers.forEach((element,index)=> {
    hashMap[element] = index;
  });

  console.log(hashMap);

  data.forEach(element => {

    let dec = true;

    conditions.forEach(elem => {
    let comparisionValue = elem[0];
    let comparisionOperator = elem[1];
    let comparisionType = elem[2];
    let comparisionHeader = elem[3];

    if(comparisionType === 'String')
    {dec = dec && eval(`'${comparisionValue}'${comparisionOperator}'${element[hashMap[comparisionHeader]]}'`);
    //console.log(`'${comparisionValue}'${comparisionOperator}'${element[hashMap[comparisionHeader]]}'`);
    }
    else if(comparisionType === 'Date')
    {
      dec = dec && eval(`${new Date(comparisionValue).getTime()}${comparisionOperator}${new Date(element[hashMap[comparisionHeader]]).getTime()}`);

    }

    else
    {
      dec = dec && eval(`${comparisionValue}${comparisionOperator}${element[hashMap[comparisionHeader]]}`);
    }

    console.log(dec);
  });

    });

    

}
```

This is my implementation, not sure if its a hacky way of getting things done or there could be any better way for the same?

for the date comparision. Not sure why that happens.

Comment: Are you asking about a hacky solution or a correct solution? There is no correct solution using `eval`.

Comment: I am asking for correct solution, if there's no correct solution using `eval` then what could be the best way?

Comment: `'date'` is the fourth element in `headers` but the fourth element in `data` is `2`.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected it thanks. But why did you say correct solution can't be using eval? What else could be the correct way then?

Comment: I would use a switch with cases for all possible operators. [You should never use `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Hmm but then how would you consider all the combinations? Like you're saying `>= <= == === < >` you will write statements for each of them>? I just got my above code working after few fixes, I want to know why do you think `eval` is unreliable?

Comment: As I said, there is a hacky way using `eval` and a correct way without `eval`. `eval` would be a reason to send you home in a job interview in all companies I've worked before. You shouldn't use it in production code and it's better to not even know about it. Often it's forbidden by static code analyzers.

Comment: I understand that you don't prefer `eval` for production based code, but all I am interested in knowing is why? Like there must be some strong reason as to oppose it right or its unreliability

Comment: There is a link in my comment. There you can find the reasons.

Comment: Another problem is that `'mm/dd/yyyy'` is not a valid date string for `new Date` or `Date.parse`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#date_time_string_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to this problem is:

```
function computeMetricwithConditions() {

  const headers = ['name', 'place', 'stats', 'score', 'date'];
  const data = [['o','b', 22, 2, '4/14/2021']];
  const conditions = [['o', '===','String','name'],['b', '===','String','place'],['4/14/2021','>=','Date','date']];
  const hashMap = {};

  headers.forEach((element,index)=> {
    hashMap[element] = index;
  });

  data.forEach(element => {
    conditions.forEach(elem => {
      let op;
      switch (elem[1]) {
          case '===':
              op = (lhs, rhs) => lhs === rhs;
              break;
          case '>=':
              op = (lhs, rhs) => lhs >= rhs;
              break;
      }
        
      let index = headers.indexOf(elem[3]);

      switch (elem[2]) {
          case 'String':
            console.log(op(toString(elem[0]), toString(element[index])));
            break;
          case 'Date':
            let date1 = elem[0].split('/');
            let date2 = element[index].split('/');
            console.log(op((new Date(date1[2], date1[0] - 1, date1[1])).getTime(), (new Date(date2[2], date2[0] - 1, date2[1])).getTime()));
            break;
      }
    });
  });
}

computeMetricwithConditions();
```

I would use switches for the different operators and types.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the operators and take an array of closures for checking the values.

```js
const
    sumif = (summationMetricHeader, header, values, condition) => {
        const
            headers = Object.fromEntries(header.map((k, v) => [k, v])),
            operators = {
                '>=': (a, b) => a >= b,
                '+': (a, b) => a + b
            },
            types = {
                Date: (...a) => a.map(getISODate),
                Number: (a, b) => [+a, +b],
                String: (...a) => a,
            },
            getISODate = string => string.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, (_, d, m, y) => `${y.padStart(4, 0)}-${m.padStart(2, 0)}-${d.padStart(2, 0)}`),
            conditions = condition
                .split(',')
                .map(s => s.split('@@'))
                .map(([left, op, type, column]) => row => operators[op](...types[type](left, row[headers[column]])));

        return values
            .filter(row => conditions.every(fn => fn(row)))
            .map(row => row[headers[summationMetricHeader]])
            .reduce(operators['+'], 0);
    },
    header = ['month', 'object', 'day', 'score'],
    values = [['dec', 'toy', '12/4/2020', 50], ['dec', 'pen', '14/4/2020', 50], ['dec', 'toy', '14/4/2020', 53], ['dec', 'toy', '4/4/2020', 50]],
    result = sumif('score', header, values, '12/4/2020@@>=@@Date@@day,50@@>=@@Number@@score');

console.log(result);
```